# Converting SQL Table ID into another field in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

So I'm trying to get the following to work;

```
//SEARCH USERPETS TABLE FOR ANYTHING USER OWNS
$query = "SELECT * FROM userpets WHERE owner = '$username'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

$userspets = $row['petid'];

//SEARCH PETS TABLE FOR LIST OF PET NAMES AND DETAILS
$query = "SELECT * FROM pets";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

$petid = $row['id']
$petname = $row['petname'];
$petimg = $row['petimg']

//TURN PET ID INTO PET NAME AND IMAGE

echo "Pets: ".$userspets;
```

Essentially what I'm trying to do is this;
The 'userpets' table contains all 'owned' pets and the players username is displayed.
I want to grab all pets owned by that user and compare the petid with the 'pets' table.
I then want to take the pet's name and image from that table and 'echo' it onto the page.

Getting all the ids is fine, I just don't know how to make it convert the id's into the names.

[Table Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BhFR.png)

Comment: use a select statement with join

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
And how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) SO is **not a free Coding or Code Conversion or Debugging or Tutorial or Library Finding service**
You also have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `JOIN` of `MYSQL` or `Foreach` of `PHP`

### This is example by using PHP Foreach

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM userpets WHERE owner = '".$username."'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

$petid = array(); // store all petid of this user

$rows = mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

foreach($rows as $row) {
    $petid[] = $row['petid'];
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM pets WHERE id IN (".implode(",",$petid).")";

// implode will convert an array to string with delimete
// example array(0=>35, 1=>36, 2=>48) will be convert to "35,36,48"
// and above query should be : SELECT * FROM pets WHERE id IN (35,36,48)

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$pets = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

// dump it 
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($pets);
echo "</pre>";
die;
```

### Using MySQL Join

```
<?php 

$query = "SELECT pet.id, pet.petname, pet.petimg, up.owner FROM pets as pet LEFT JOIN userpets as up ON pet.id = up.pet_id WHERE up.owner = '".$username."'";
```

Comment: The `JOIN` solution is a lot better and really should be the first part of your answer. The messy stuff with `implode` is problematic.

Comment: At sometime, `foreach loop` will faster than `Join SQL` :) there are two ways. Thanks for your comment

Comment: It's rare that the `foreach` version performs faster, every query contains a pretty sizeable latency penalty. A well indexed table will always `JOIN` faster.

Comment: First, the var_dump($pets) - I believe needs a ; after it, as I got an error without.

Second, the result returns 'Null' - Any ideas?

Comment: Can you var_dump two `$query` ?

Comment: @Kamata Because I don't know your `table structure` you should show it

Comment: When I do that it prints: string(40) "SELECT * FROM pets WHERE id IN (1,1,1,K)"

Comment: @Kamata Can you var_dump result of this query ? `"SELECT * FROM userpets WHERE owner = '".$username."'"`

Comment: Doing that then gives me the username: string(45) "SELECT * FROM userpets WHERE owner = 'Kamata'" -- (Also, here is the table structure https://i.gyazo.com/d7faf3133f3d9dfbd766b510371dddf9.png )

Comment: @Kamata can you show the `$result` of above query ?

Comment: Ahh I see. Sorry. The $result: bool(false)

Comment: @Kamata It's mean the query fail, can you query it on phpmyadmin ? Have result or not ? and var_dump the `$row`

Comment: Sorry again, I did the result for the wrong query; object(mysqli_result)#4 (5) {
  ["current_field"]=>
  int(0)
  ["field_count"]=>
  int(12)
  ["lengths"]=>
  array(12) {
    [0]=>
    int(1)
    [1]=>
    int(6)
    [2]=>
    int(16)
    [3]=>
    int(60)
    [4]=>
    int(3)
    [5]=>
    int(5)
    [6]=>
    int(5)
    [7]=>
    int(5)
    [8]=>
    int(1)
    [9]=>
    int(2)
    [10]=>
    int(4)
    [11]=>
    int(2)
  }
  ["num_rows"]=>
  int(1)
  ["type"]=>
  int(0)
}

Comment: @Kamata It looks okay. var_dump the `$rows`

Comment: rows: array(4) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["userid"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["petid"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["owner"]=>
  string(6) "Kamata"
}

Comment: @Kamata should use mysqli_fetch_all() because one user maybe have many pet and use mysqli_fetch_all() will return all rows one time, if use mysqli_fetch_assoc() you must use while() to loop the rows

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how your tables look, but the best thing I can think of is, you have 3 tables one with `Users`, second with `pets`, and third "many to many" table lets call it `ownedpets` with users that own pets, because many users can own many pets. So `ownedpets` should have `id_users` that is connected to `user.id` and `id_pets` which is connected to `pets_id`. With that in mind I would do the fallowing query

```
SELECT *
FROM ownedpets
LEFT JOIN users
ON users.id = ownedpets.id_users
LEFT JOIN pets
ON pets.id = ownedpets.id_pets
WHERE users.id = $user_id
```

hope this helps